# Nuget.Versioning.SemanticVersion.ToString(format) examples?

Tags: nuget, semantic-versioning

I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere on what formats one can pass in to `.ToString()` on `NuGet.Versioning.SemanticVersion`. The value seems to be indexing into a list of `_formatters` but there's no docs on what values are available by default, what the default behavior is, how to tweak it, etc.

e.g. this is all that's in the source code:

```cs
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gives a normalized representation of the version. This string is unique to the
        //     identity of the version and does not contain metadata.
        public virtual string ToNormalizedString()
        {
            return ToString("N", VersionFormatter.Instance);
        }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gives a full representation of the version include metadata. This string is not
        //     unique to the identity of the version. Other versions that differ on metadata
        //     will have a different full string representation.
        public virtual string ToFullString()
        {
            return ToString("F", VersionFormatter.Instance);
        }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Get the normalized string.
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ToNormalizedString();
        }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Custom string format.
        public virtual string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        {
            string formattedString = null;
            if (formatProvider == null || !TryFormatter(format, formatProvider, out formattedString))
            {
                formattedString = ToString();
            }

            return formattedString;
        }
```

Anybody know where I can find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close to finding the list of format characters yourself!

The first two methods you copied into your question reference a property `VersionFormatter.Instance`. Looking at the `VersionFormatter` class, the `Format` method enumerates the list of characters it handles: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/08a7a7bd17e504d808329dcc1ffc866d9f59d040/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Versioning/VersionFormatter.cs#L65-L101

| character | method |
| --- | --- |
| N | `AppendNormalized(builder, version);` |
| V | `AppendVersion(builder, version);` |
| F | `AppendFull(builder, version);` |
| R | `builder.Append(version.Release);` |
| M | `builder.Append(version.Metadata);` |
| x | `builder.Append(version.Major);` |
| y | `builder.Append(version.Minor);` |
| z | `builder.Append(version.Patch);` |
| r | `builder.Append(version is NuGetVersion nuGetVersion && nuGetVersion.IsLegacyVersion ? nuGetVersion.Version.Revision : 0);` |

Comment: Thanks a ton - though I wish this was in docs somewhere w/ examples :/